# PHP Framework large numbers of include function

Tags: php, include, server

We are adapting a clients PHP framework to be more efficient.

Is there anything fundamentally bad in design to have a framework highly dependent on PHP INCLUDE.

Essentially every function, element or panel that exists on a page has a separate CSS file, JS file, PHP Functions File (where needed) and index file containing the HTML.

This method is very nice to work with as everything is effectively self contained but are there any issues that this design would cause in terms of load time on servers etc...

Thanks,

Comment: fwiw, there is something fundamentally badly designed in the entire `include` story in PHP.

Comment: Well it means browsers wont be able to cache resources, so each request will require redownloading

Answer (score 1):

There are a few items to be aware of:

- Loading everything through a PHP include and not grouping anything will lead to a lot of disk i/o or reading from files in from memory, requiring a diff check against the disk, unless you use APC or some other cache.
- Loading all of the css and js files will lead to an http roundtrip for each one. Your JS will block everything while downloading. All of that adds up to slower first render time for a user.
- You're probably not following DRY (Do not repeat yourself) principles, because it will requiring digging through a treasure trove of files

I'm sure there are more reasons not to do things this way. There isn't anything inherently wrong exactly, but it sounds like a strange way to structure a project.

Comment: I suppose I should add that this site involves no page loads with AJAX used for virtually everything. One of the advantages of the way it is built is that only the components wanted are ever part of the AJAX load. Even unnecessary PHP functions are not looped through.